# count how may values are larger than specific number which however is already in specific line in a different file

Tags: awk

I have two files

First file, namely file1, contains three lines with the following values

```
   17.503766
   17.252752
   17.348948
```

Second file, namely frame1 contains following values

```
  38.730
  17.270
  24.370
  45.180
  46.510
```

Target is to count how many of those values from frame1 file are larger than value which is presented in line1 of file1.

So will be something similar to below however I don't know how to set this as a criterion

```
awk '($1>??){ ++count } END{ print count }' 'frame1' > 'file-new'
```

Comment: [edit] your question to include concise, testable sample input (i.e. contents of file1 and file2) and expected output. See [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{ if (FNR==1) tgt=$1; next } $1 > tgt{ ++count } END{ print count+0 }' file1 frame1
4
```

With GNU awk you can replace:

```
if (FNR==1) tgt=$1; next
```

with the following for efficiency:

```
tgt=$1; nextfile
```

Comment: I am really grateful for your reply. Also in case I have frame2, frame3 etc. and I want to compare their values to the value presented in line 2 and line 3 of file1 respectively how can I modify the above command?

Comment: ok managed to do this. Instead, I have defined a for do variable,i, and replaced (FNR==1) with (FNR=='$i')

Comment: Don't do that, it's the wrong approach and using the wrong syntax even for that approach. Ask a followup question.

Answer (score 0):

Tried with below command

```
#Below Command fetches highest value from file1
```

k=`awk 'BEGIN{sum=0}($1 > sum){sum=$1}END{print sum}' file1`

```
#Below command will display value from file2 which is greater  when compared with file1


awk -v k="$k" '$1 > k {print $1}' file2
```